# python compare float vlaues with different precesion values (decimals)

Tags: python, list

i have a input value 1234.1 and list with
**[ '1234.567', '1234.123', '1234.110']**
if condition to compare the list with  input value and expected output is set to True in 2 cases

**Output**
***1234.123*** and ***1234.110***

Comment: Why **Output 1234.123 and 124.110**

Comment: The question is not clear. I suggest you rephrase to make it clearer.

Comment: its a typo i think. he means 1234.123 and 1234.110

Answer (score 0):

You can compare them taking the substring value that you want to compare:

```
list_values = ['1234.567', '1234.123', '1234.110'] # Your values
input_value = 1234.1 # the input value to compare
numbers_dec = 1 # number of decimals to consider comparing

for v in list_values:
    # You took the substring from 0 to the point plus the number of decimals that you consider
    tmp = v[0:v.index('.')+numbers_dec+1]
    if(str(input_value) == tmp):
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Not valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

why go to this length as @Diego suggested.You can use math.isclose() for comparing like this.

```
import math

nums = [ '1234.567', '1234.123', '1234.110']
input = 1234.1

output = False
for val in nums:
  if math.isclose(float(val),input,rel_tol=1e+9, abs_tol=0.0):
    output = True

print(output)
```

where rel_tol is relative tolerance and abs_tol is absolute tolerance.
refer [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want:

```
from decimal import localcontext

with localcontext as context
   context.prec(1)
   # inside this block (the context), should be evaluated as having .1
   # precision. Therefore, your list, inside this block, would evaluate 
   # to ['1234.5, 1234.1, 1234.1].
```

The localcontext module/ submodule lets you change the precision temporarily inside the code block. You can define the list outside, then refer to it inside the block to achieve the precision you need for your calculation. You can find out more about the module [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#context-objects). I am assuming Python 2 as I believe the convention is still python = python 2 and python3 = python 3. Not sure if this module works with python 3 or not. Maybe add a version to your question.